# Webclient DownloadString Freezing the main Form

Tags: c#, multithreading, webclient

hope somebody can help me with my problem.

I am trying to get the html code of a web site using the following code:

```
        public string DownloadString(string add)
        {
            string html = "";            
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Proxy = null;
                client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
                while (html == "")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        html = client.DownloadString(add);

                    }
                    catch (WebException e)
                    {
                        html = "";
                    }
                }
                client.Dispose();
            }
            return html;
        }
```

And I need the string in this function(Caller):

```
        public HtmlNode get_html(string add)
        {
            add_val(add);
            Uri madd = new Uri(add);
            Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Task<string> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<string>
        (() => DownloadString(add));
            string html = task.Result;
            //string html = DownloadString(add);
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            //doc.Load(new StringReader(html));
            doc.LoadHtml(html);
            HtmlNode root = doc.DocumentNode; 
            timer.Stop();
            TimeSpan timespan = timer.Elapsed;
            label18.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds, timespan.Milliseconds / 10);            
            return root;
        }
```

I have tried `html = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(add));` but it doesn't seem to work, it still freezes the UI when i download a string.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use WebClient without blocking UI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118796/how-to-use-webclient-without-blocking-ui)

Comment: i tried that and it still freezes UI.

Comment: you are still running on the same thread of your UI... please use **BackgroundWorker**.. very similar to a **Timer** - will grant you to runcode without freezing stuff

Comment: how do i get the result from the backgroundworker?

Comment: call to `task.Result` is always blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prevent blocking the UI, your code needs to be asynchronous *all the way*.

This code in particular is blocking the UI thread until the download completes:

```
Task<string> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() => DownloadString(add));
string html = task.Result;
```

What you need is to use `await` instead:

```
Task<string> task = Task.Run(() => DownloadString(add));
string html = await task;
```

This means your `get_html` method must be `async`:

```
public async Task<HtmlNode> get_htmlAsync(string add)
```

And all of its callers must use `await`, and become `async`, etc. You have to allow the asynchrony to grow all the way through the caller tree.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that call to `task.Result` is always blocking (if task is not ready, calling thread will wait for completion), so your UI thread will be blocked, waiting for task result. What you need to do, if you are using .Net Framework 4 (@Stephen wrote a solution for 4.5) is to use continuation in a following way.

```
public void get_html(string add)
        {
            add_val(add);
            Uri madd = new Uri(add);
            Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() => DownloadString(add))
                .ContinueWith(t => {
                    string html = task.Result;
                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                    doc.LoadHtml(html);
                    HtmlNode root = doc.DocumentNode; 
                    timer.Stop();
                    TimeSpan timespan = timer.Elapsed;
                    label18.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", timespan.Minutes, timespan.Seconds, timespan.Milliseconds / 10);            
                    //
                    Update UI with results here
                    //
                }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }
```

Alternatively you can set `get_html` return type to `Task<string>` or `Task<HtmlNode>` in order to use continuation on it.